# Making bullet points of enumerate to horizontally align on the left instead of right

Tags: enumerate

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=5mm, noitemsep]
\item[\textbf{1}] \hspace{1mm} Text here
\item[\textbf{2}] \hspace{1mm} Text here
\item[\textbf{3}] \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=1cm, noitemsep]
        \item[\textbf{(a)}] Text here
        \item[\textbf{(b)}] Text here
        \item[\textbf{(c)}] Text here
        \item[] Text here
        \item[\textbf{(d)}] Text here
    \end{enumerate}
\item[\textbf{4}] \hspace{1mm} Text here
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The above code gives the following output:

[image]

My problem with this is that the `(a), (b), etc.` bullet points are lined up at their closing parenthesis. I want them to **start** together at their opening parenthesis instead. Is this possible?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To align the items to the left, you can use the keyword `align=left` in the corresponding `enumerate` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=5mm, noitemsep]
\item[\textbf{1}] \hspace{1mm} Text here
\item[\textbf{2}] \hspace{1mm} Text here
\item[\textbf{3}] \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=1cm, noitemsep, align=left]
        \item[\textbf{(a)}] Text here
        \item[\textbf{(b)}] Text here
        \item[\textbf{(c)}] Text here
        \item[] Text here
        \item[\textbf{(d)}] Text here
    \end{enumerate}
\item[\textbf{4}] \hspace{1mm} Text here
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Also, it is unrelated to your specific question, but you should know that you don't have to enter manually the label of each item: everything can be made automatic, including the formatting. For example, the following code yields pretty much exactly the same output as the last one (except maybe a tiny different in horizontal spacing).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{
    noitemsep,
    label=\textbf{\arabic*},
    labelwidth=6mm,
    labelsep=4mm,
}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{
    noitemsep,
    label=\textbf{(\alph*)},
    labelwidth=6mm,
    labelsep=2mm,
    labelindent=0mm,
    leftmargin=!,
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Text here
\item Text here
\item \begin{enumerate}[align=left]
        \item Text here
        \item Text here
        \item Text here
        \item[] Text here
        \item Text here
    \end{enumerate}
\item Text here
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: May I ask what does the `labelwidth`, `labelsep`, `labelindent`, `leftmargin` in your second code mean?

Comment: @EnergeticElectrification They control the horizontal spacing. Everything is explained in detail in [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)'s documentation, in section 3.2.